# What's the best way to scale i18n translations in an enterprise software model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Let's say I have a really simple rails app that runs on one 1 app server and supports one language (`en_US`).

The `i18n` gem works great and provides all translations as read from my `en.yml` file. Woohoo.

But let's say I scale my app and it now supports the following -

- Enterprise versions of the app, so it runs on several app (and db) servers
- Multiple languages other than `en_US` (e.g. `ja_JP`, `ms_MY`, `en_GB`, etc..)

I'm now supporting multiple instances of the app, each with several `*.yml` files that are starting to pile up. Plus, the app is getting more complex so each YML file is getting huge because there are a lot of translations.

Is there a clean way to move these YML files and `i18n` translations out of the core app? I'm envisioning an HTTP that functions as an "`i18n` service". Every time an app starts up it queries the `i18n` service and gets all the translations it needs for particular locale.

Is this a scalable way to approach this? Anyone have any experience in using a different design pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can break one large yml file into several ones, and even distribute files in subdirectories.

For instance your localization tree might look like this:

```
locales/
  models/
    user_en.yml
    user_jp.yml
    product_en.yml
    product_jp.yml
  pages/
    index_en.yml
    index_jp.yml
  en.yml
  jp.yml
```

To include all yml files from this tree, modify you application.rb accordingly:

```
 config.i18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```